# Flutter Dart get list of string from list of objects

Tags: flutter, dart

**I have a list of objects (City) that contains a lot of properties it's internal structure:**

```
class City {
  String id;
  String name;
  String parent_id;
  double lat;
  double lng;
  String local;
}
```

how to get a list of names(Strings) from the same list of cities

```
List<City> cities
```

how to get `List<String> names` from cities

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use [map](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.2/dart-core/Iterable/map.html). Tutorial [here](https://dart.dev/codelabs/iterables#mapping).

For example:

```dart
class City {
  const City(this.id, this.name);

  final int id;
  final String name;
}

List<City> cities = [
  City(0, 'A'),
  City(1, 'B'),
  City(2, 'C'),
];

final List<String> cityNames = cities.map((city) => city.name).toList();

void main() {
  print(cityNames);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's simple and cumbersome though,

```
var cityNames = cities.map((c) => c.name).toList().join(',');
```

Answer (score 3):

**Use this**

```
    List<String> cityNameList = cities.map((city) => city.name).toList();
```

*You can also go through explanation below*

**CustomData Class**

```
 class City {
    String id;
    String name;
    String parent_id;
    double lat;
    double lng;
    String local;
}
```

**Map `List<City>` to `List<String>`** based on any member of City class

```
List<City> cities= getListOfCities();
// city.name, city.local...any field as you wish
List<String> cityNameList = cities.map((city) => city.name).toList();
print(cityNameList);
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, if you want to extract a list of string from list of object, with selected or enabled flag.

To do that, you can remove objects with `selected=false` or something like `name.length > 5`, then do `map.tolist` to extract the list of string.

Usually i use this method to get filters to filtering search result. Example we have a products list with distance & country filters. We can simply use solution above and apply filter with selected true.

I don't speak english, hope you understand .

```dart
class City {
  const City(this.name, [this.selected= false]);

  final String name;
  final bool selected;
}

void main() {
  final cities = [City('A'), City('B', true), City('C')];
  cities.add(City('D', true));
  
  /// Remove unselected items
  cities.removeWhere((e) => !e.selected);
   
  /// extract list of string from list of objects
  final selectedCities = cities.map((c) => c.name).toList();

  print(selectedCities);
}
```

print:

```
[B, D]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> names=[];

for (City city in cities){
names.add(city.name);
 }
```